# How to label duplicate entries in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, import, duplicates

I'm using `MySQL 5.0.88/Coldfusion` and have a temporary table which I'm loading a CSV file into. This table gets validated and then imported to the main database.

I need to run a check for duplicate imports in the temporary table. I'm checking the temp table like this:

```
<cfquery datasource="db">
    UPDATE import_temp
    SET error= "true", errorMsg = "missing info"
    WHERE user = <cfqueryparam value = "#Session.user#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="13"> 
    AND error = "false" 
    AND info = ""
</cfquery>
```

**Question**:
Is it possible to do a check on the temporary table for duplicate ids like so:

```
<cfquery datasource="db">
    UPDATE import_temp
    SET error = "true", errorMsg = "duplicate id"
    WHERE user = <cfqueryparam value = "#Session.user#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="13"> 
    AND error = "false" 
    AND id IN (SELECT i.id FROM import_temp AS i WHERE i.id = id)
</cfquery>
```

Now this doesn't work, but is there a way to make it work and set the error field to false like this? Or is the only way using `on duplicate key` when loading the CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE import_temp
SET error = "true", errorMsg = "duplicate id"
WHERE user = <cfqueryparam value = "#Session.user#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="13"> 
AND error = "false" 
AND id IN (SELECT id FROM permanent WHERE import_temp.id = id)
```

Comment: seems I was close... :-) Let me try.

Comment: Sorry to have to come back. It's not working... I'm getting: You can't specify target table 'i' for update in FROM clause . You make something out of it?

Comment: @frequent I tested something similar here and it worked. But thinking about what you want it is better that it does not work because it will not do that. It will simple turn all rows false as true.

Comment: ok :-D you have a better idea? I need to have some way of labelling dupicate entries when loading the CSV file into my temp table.

Comment: @frequent I changed it to what I think you want (compare the temp to the permanent table).

Comment: not quite. I'm loading the CSV, label all errors (including dulplicates) and only import the non-error rows to the actual table. Need to think about this some more.

Comment: @frequent Changed again to avoid the `alias` in case that is what it is warning about.

Comment: I have an ugly solution... see below :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Doing it like this for now...:

```
<cfquery datasource="db" name="dups">
    SELECT ean 
    FROM import_pricat_csv
    WHERE iln = <cfqueryparam value = "#Session.loginID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="13"> 
    AND fehler = "nein"
    AND ean IN (
        SELECT ean
        FROM import_pricat_csv
        GROUP BY ean
        HAVING count(ean) > 1
        )
</cfquery>
<cfif dups.recordcount GT 0>
    <cfloop query="dups">
        <cfquery datasource="db">
            UPDATE import_pricat_csv
            SET fehler = "ja", fehlertext = "EAN doppelt"
            WHERE ean = dups.ean
        </cfquery>
    </cfloop>
</cfif>
```

Not nice, but seems to work.